# Download Powershell Documentation

Tags: powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/?view=powershell-6

In this website there's a left navbar with a section called Reference which contains each one of the Powershell commands, each one with an explanation and examples. I would like to print it to read it offline, but it's gonna take me weeks to copy and paste everything into a document. Isn't there a PDF or some document I can download that contains the contents of the Reference section? I can't find such thing. I'm open to ideas, like writing a Powershell script to store all the commands, their descriptions and examples into a file. I'm open to anything but manually copy and paste. Does Microsoft have a downloadable version? If not, how would you do it?

I've found this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/tree/staging/reference/6

It's a good start, but still seems like a lot of work to print everything.
If not printing, perhaps put all the md files into a single file that can be read with an ebook?

Answer (score 0):

A student/any scripter should run `Get-Help help` and then `Get-Help $TopicsYouCareAbout` as you go. You will occasionally need to `Update-Help` but you will always have a plethora of valuable documentation on MS documentation at your fingertips for any module that you install.

You can also generate markdown documentation from this generated documentation using the [platyPS](https://github.com/PowerShell/platyPS) module. You will need to install the module you want to generate documentation for first.

```
Install-Module -Name platyPS 
Import-Module platyPS

$modules = @('platyPS','Microsoft.PowerShell.Management')
foreach($module in $modules){
    New-MarkdownHelp -OutputFolder "C:\PSGeneratedDocs" -Module $module
}
```

This spits out a bunch of markdown files into `C:\PSGeneratedDocs`. You can take it a step further and publish pdf/epub/other format with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) (You will need to ensure you have a pdf engine installed for this step, but there are alot of resources to help depending on your platform/needs for the finished book.

```
foreach($mdFile in (Get-ChildItem "C:\PGGeneratedDocs" | where {$_.Extension -eq ".md"})){
    pandoc -s $mdFile -o "C:\PGGeneratedDocs\$($mdFile.BaseName).pdf"
}
```

monitoring their git repository would be essentially the same, but more complex with little extra gain for you.